# Maximizing the size of a rectangle inside a rectangle

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, area

I'm an engineer who hasn't done calculus in a while, but I know there's a way to figure this out with a summation or a differential or something.

I need to make a rectangle (length of $x$, width of $y$) inside another rectangle (length of $a$, width of $b$) such that they both have the same resulting area $\left(xy=\dfrac{ab}{2}\right)$. Also, $0<x<a$ and $0<y<b$.

How do I figure this out?

[image]

Comment: A diagram of the configuration you are thinking about would help.

Comment: I think $x=\frac{a}{2} \ , \ y = \frac{b}{2}$ does the job

Comment: You mean $x = \frac{a}{\sqrt2}, y = \frac{b}{\sqrt2}$, right?

Comment: @JoshuaWang - I added a picture to the original post.

Comment: There is more than one such rectangle. For example, you could also say $x=a/\sqrt{3}$ and $y=b\sqrt{3}/2$. What are you trying to maximize?

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi That results in xy = ab/4. I did the same thing though when I first started working on it.

Comment: @Cole In the title you want to maximize the size of the rectangle. But you do not maximize anything. the size is already given as ab/2.

Comment: If you have $x=k\cdot a$ and $y=\ell\cdot b$, all you need is that $k\cdot \ell = \frac 12$. If you don't like irrationals, there are plenty of rational fractions that will do the job, e.g. choosing $k,\ell$ to be $\frac 23, \frac 34$ in some order.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways. Pick any number $r$ between $1/2$ and $1$. Let
$x = ar$ and $y = b/2r$. Then put the smaller rectangle anywhere inside the larger.

A natural way to do this is to use $r=\sqrt{2}/2$. Then the small rectangle will be the same shape as the large one.